# Passing a memoized function to onPress of a component issue

Tags: reactjs, react-native, callback, react-usememo

Assume I have the following component:

```
 <TouchableOpacity
        style={...}
        onPress={() => func(x)}
      >
<TouchableOpacity/>
```

and func() defined as follows:

```
const func = (x) => {console.log("help please")}
```

This work as it should. However, once I memoize func() as follows:

```
const func = useMemo(()=>throttle(500,true, (x)=>{console.log("help please")}
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: callback.apply is not a function. (In 'callback.apply(self, arguments_)', 'callback.apply' is undefined)
```

Note:
throttle was imported:

```
import { throttle } from "throttle-debounce";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the `true` argument as it isn't specified in the docs

```
throttle(500, (x)=>{console.log("help please")
```

Comment: you were right, to get this straight.. so callback.apply is not a function implies that too much arguments are being passed to the callback?

Comment: As you can see in the [source code](https://github.com/niksy/throttle-debounce/blob/master/throttle.js#L71) this function tries to run `.apply()` on the second argument of the function called `callback`. You passed `true` as a second argument, so it tries to do `true.apply()`. `true.apply` is `undefined` so i tries to call `undefined` as if it was a function